# E-mail issue in Confluence with Jira filter

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-filter

I craeted a page in confluence with Jira filters. When I try to do mail the page using the provision "`Email This Page`". I am getting the following preview,

[image]

Only the static data is loaded but the data from Jira filter is not loaded to the mail content. How can I mail the Jira filter data from Confluence?

Converting to PDF works fine with Jira filter data.

Comment: Yes, I see that too. I recommend using the Share button to send a link to the page, and suggest that people click on the link. Email is not a great communication platform in general!

Comment: Yeah that is one way of doing it. but what if the the person not have access to the actual server ?